# How to init a register with a parametrized value

Tags: scala, chisel

I'm trying to deploy RegInit in a module with parametrized data types. Normally, for a simple port in Chisel I'd do the following:

```
val myReg = RegInit (0.U(32.W))
```

In my code, I have the following:

```
import dsptools._
import dsptools.numbers._

class Acc[A <: Data:Ring, B <: Data:Ring] (inType:A, outType:B, 

mulPipeLen:Int = 1, addPipeLen:Int = 1) extends Module {
...
  def zero = dsptools.numbers.Ring[B].zero

  val mres  = Reg(outType.cloneType) // this works, no initialization
  val ares  = RegInit(zero(outType.cloneType.getWidth.W)) // this fails trying to zero init in the parametrized Ring
...

}
```

which return a compile error:

```
[error] Acc.scala:43:27: B does not take parameters
[error]   val mres  = RegInit(zero(outType.cloneType.cloneType.getWidth.W))
```

How do I fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I tried the above, I got 3 errors:

```
[error] /Users/jack/work/chisel3-raw/src/main/scala/RegInit.scala:10:13: inferred type arguments [Object] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [T <: chisel3.core.Data]
[error]   val reg = RegInit(0.U, (32.W))
[error]             ^
[error] /Users/jack/work/chisel3-raw/src/main/scala/RegInit.scala:10:23: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : chisel3.core.UInt
[error]  required: T
[error]   val reg = RegInit(0.U, (32.W))
[error]                       ^
[error] /Users/jack/work/chisel3-raw/src/main/scala/RegInit.scala:10:30: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : chisel3.internal.firrtl.Width
[error]  required: T
[error]   val reg = RegInit(0.U, (32.W))
[error]                              ^
```

RegInit has two flavors, documented here: https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/api/latest/chisel3/core/RegInit$.html

In short, if just 1 argument, it is the initialization value. If the initialization value has a defined width (`0.U(32.W)` vs. `0.U`) then it will adopt the width (and type) of the initializing value.

```
val reg = RegInit(0.U(32.W))
```

Otherwise, you can give 2 arguments, the first defining the type, the second defining the initialization value

```
val reg2 = RegInit(UInt(32.W), 0.U)
```

**Response to Edited post**

I don't know much about the dsptools, but I don't think `Ring` has much to do with the concept of zero. You can set the type of `ares` to be the same as `outType` and then try casting 0 to the same type as the init value, eg.

```
val ares = RegInit(outType.cloneType, 0.U.asTypeOf(outType.cloneType))
```

Or perhaps you can cast 0 and also set the width:

```
val ares = RegInit(0.U(outType.getWidth.W).asTypeOf(outType.cloneType))
```

I'm not sure if these will work, but they might

Comment: Hi Jack. Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to implement a Facade for an Abstract Factory and need to initialize some variables. @ChickMarkley helped me with this project in past. I need to pass Double, FixedPoint and Complex numbers and initialize Facade vars appropriately. Pls check an updated code and provide an updated solution. Thank you!

Comment: I've updated my response with something that *might* work

Comment: Both updated versions work fine. I picked the 2-nd, since its closer to official documentation for Chisel3. Thank you!